# FB.login(null, {scope: 'publish_actions'}); crash

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Today I came across a very irritating issue. My JavaScript stopped working over night. When a user tries to create a FB action on my page there is a funky JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__wrapped' of null
```

Error occurs in the `connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js:82` and it doesn't make sense. In the error chain last line called from my script is `FB.login(null, {scope: 'publish_actions'});`. There is no AJAX called to Facebook. The JS SDK crashes before it gets anywhere. What is more annoying an old version of my script on different environment works so I can't blame facebook. Do you have any idea where should I look for a problem?

Comment: Check the parameters you are passing to `FB.login` in your old working sample.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't be passing `null` as the first argument.

Comment: Parameter are exactly the same FB.login(null, {scope: 'publish_actions'});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right syntax of FB.login is

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

**Why are you passing null as the parameter**? That should contain the function which will process the response received.

At the very least, pass it an empty function, with no body.

(**[Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)**)

Comment: And if you don’t want to do anything with the response, then just give an empty function object as parameter: `function() {}`

Comment: Thank you @Cthulhu. That was the issue indeed. I didn't need a callback because I hooked into the "auth.authResponseChange" event. I thought it's better to have a null instead of an empty anonymous function. Strangely it was working for a while. Anyway.. Thank you.